# MaxScale Connects to MySQL replica but cannot execute queries

Tags: mysql, mariadb, load-balancing, maxscale

I am setting up a Master-slave MySQL replication setup using 3 MySQL 8 nodes(Fresh installations). I have setup a master and configured another nodes to replicate from the master which is working fine.

I have setup MaxScale as a load balancer and I am intending to use it as a load balancer with read write splitting. Following is my setup(domain names are anonymized for privacy reasons).

```
node1.com - master
node2.com - slave1
```

I can succesfully connect both nodes with `mysql -uroot -proot -h . Following is my MaxScale configuration.

```
[maxscale]
threads=auto
admin_secure_gui=false
admin_host=0.0.0.0

[node1]
type=server
address=node1.com
port=3306
protocol=MySQLBackend

[node2]
type=server
address=node2.com
port=3306
protocol=MySQLBackend

[node3]
type=server
address=node3.com
port=3306
protocol=MySQLBackend


[MySQL-Monitor]
type=monitor
module=mariadbmon
servers=node1,node2,node3
user=maxscale
password=password
monitor_interval=2s

[Read-Write-Service]
type=service
router=readwritesplit
servers=node1,node2
user=maxscale
password=password
enable_root_user=true

[Read-Write-Listener]
type=listener
service=Read-Write-Service
protocol=MariaDBClient
port=3307
```

When I try `mysql -uroot -proot -h <maxscale-domain>` Maxscale can succesfully connect to the server, but the connection hangs as follows.

```
➜  ~ mysql -uroot -proot -h <maxscale-domain> -P 3307
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
```

How can i resolve this?

I have tried the followings to try to debug this.

1. Using a new read only service with following configuration

```
[Read-Service]
type=service
router=readconnroute
servers=node1,node2
router_options=master
user=maxscale
password=password
enable_root_user=true

[Read-Listener]
type=listener
service=Read-Service
protocol=MariaDBClient
port=3306
```

This has led me somewhere with `mysql -uroot -proot` as it allows me to connect to both servers succesfully. When `router_options=master` I can successfully connect to master and query the database. However when `router_options=slave` I can connect to the slave but cannot query it.

```
➜  ~ mysql -uroot -proot -h <maxscale-host> -P 3306
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 7
Server version: 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select @@hostname;
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    8
Current database: *** NONE ***

ERROR 1927 (HY000): Lost connection to backend server: network error (node2, Connection refused)
```

This led me to believe the issue could be with the node2, but I cannot figure out the issue as it works fine if i connect the mysql client directly to node.

2. To ensure that this is not a issue related to any slave, i removed node1 from the network and added a new node3. Then node2 is setup as the master of node3 with replication enabled. Results for the Read only service is as follows.

With `router_options=master` :

```
➜  ~ mysql -uroot -proot -h <maxscale-host> -P 3306
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select @@hostname;
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    2
Current database: *** NONE ***

ERROR 1927 (HY000): Lost connection to backend server: network error (node2, Connection refused)
```

It provides the same issue for node2 and 3 both now.

With `router_options=slave` :

```
➜  ~ mysql -uroot -proot -h <maxscale-host> -P 3306
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select @@hostname;
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    2
Current database: *** NONE ***

ERROR 1927 (HY000): Lost connection to backend server: network error (node3, Connection refused)
```

Note that all 3 are plain MySQL installations with few empty databases added + binlog enabled. Replication works fine and MaxScale GUI reports as such. It looks like the issue comes from MySQL, but actually it should be related to the MaxScale.

Any thoughts on the matter are highly appreciated.

Edit : Attaching maxscale.log

```
MariaDB MaxScale  /var/log/maxscale/maxscale.log  Fri May  5 13:27:43 2023
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-05-05 13:27:43   notice : Module 'mariadbmon' loaded from '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/maxscale/libmariadbmon.so'.
2023-05-05 13:27:43   notice : Module 'readconnroute' loaded from '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/maxscale/libreadconnroute.so'.
2023-05-05 13:27:43   notice : Module 'readwritesplit' loaded from '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/maxscale/libreadwritesplit.so'.
2023-05-05 13:27:43   notice : Using up to 75.53GiB of memory for query classifier cache
2023-05-05 13:27:43   notice : syslog logging is disabled.
2023-05-05 13:27:43   notice : maxlog logging is enabled.
2023-05-05 13:27:43   notice : Host: '<maxscale-host>' OS: Linux@5.4.0-135-generic, #152-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 23 20:19:22 UTC 2022, x86_64 with 64 processor cores (64.00 available).
2023-05-05 13:27:43   notice : Total main memory: 503.56GiB (503.56GiB usable).
2023-05-05 13:27:43   notice : MariaDB MaxScale 23.02.1 started (Commit: 5de96ecc39da80a992fc8f362d22a030a844bef5)
2023-05-05 13:27:43   notice : MaxScale is running in process 3097068
2023-05-05 13:27:43   notice : Configuration file: /etc/maxscale.cnf
2023-05-05 13:27:43   notice : Log directory: /var/log/maxscale
2023-05-05 13:27:43   notice : Data directory: /var/lib/maxscale
2023-05-05 13:27:43   notice : Module directory: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/maxscale
2023-05-05 13:27:43   notice : Service cache: /var/cache/maxscale
2023-05-05 13:27:43   notice : Working directory: /var/log/maxscale
2023-05-05 13:27:43   notice : Module 'qc_sqlite' loaded from '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/maxscale/libqc_sqlite.so'.
2023-05-05 13:27:43   notice : Query classification results are cached and reused. Memory used per thread: 1.18GiB
2023-05-05 13:27:43   notice : Password encryption key file '/var/lib/maxscale/.secrets' not found, using configured passwords as plaintext.
2023-05-05 13:27:43   notice : The systemd watchdog is Enabled. Internal timeout = 30s
2023-05-05 13:27:43   notice : Using HS256 for JWT signatures
2023-05-05 13:27:43   notice : Started REST API on [0.0.0.0]:8989
```

Edit 2:

Attaching mysql general log for reference. Nothing specific to logging or execution of the query gets logged in the mysql general log either. However when i restart the maxscale server it succesfull y connects it seems which is proven by the statement `2023-05-05T11:45:44.693829Z       19 Connect   maxscale@<maxscale-host> on  using TCP/IP`

```
2023-05-05T11:45:44.226596Z    18 Query SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Uptime'
2023-05-05T11:45:44.228199Z    18 Query SELECT @@global.server_id, @@read_only
2023-05-05T11:45:44.228584Z    18 Query SHOW SLAVE STATUS
2023-05-05T11:45:44.532309Z    18 Quit  
2023-05-05T11:45:44.693829Z    19 Connect   maxscale@<maxscale-host> on  using TCP/IP
2023-05-05T11:45:44.694243Z    19 Quit  
2023-05-05T11:45:44.695671Z    20 Connect   maxscale@<maxscale-host> on  using TCP/IP
2023-05-05T11:45:44.696020Z    20 Query SET SQL_MODE=''
2023-05-05T11:45:44.696292Z    20 Query SET @@session.autocommit=1
2023-05-05T11:45:44.696512Z    20 Query SET NAMES latin1
2023-05-05T11:45:44.696768Z    20 Query SELECT id, @@global.collation_server FROM information_schema.collations WHERE collation_name=@@global.collation_server
```

Edit 3: Attaching MaxScale info log as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/7633996/markusjm

```
2023-05-08 11:05:34   info   : Routed [COM_QUERY] to 'node-a' select @@version_comment limit 1
2023-05-08 11:05:34   info   : Storing COM_QUERY while in state 'Handshaking': select @@version_comment limit 1
2023-05-08 11:05:34   info   : Server 'node-a' failed
2023-05-08 11:05:34   info   : Stopped Read-Service client session [1]
2023-05-08 11:05:38   info   : Accept authentication from 'admin', using password. Request: /auth
2023-05-08 11:05:44   info   : Found matching user 'maxscale'@'%' for client 'maxscale'@'2001:1458:202:56::111:1b' with sufficient privileges.
2023-05-08 11:05:44   info   : New session for server node-a. Connections : 1
2023-05-08 11:05:44   info   : Started Read-Service client session [2] for 'maxscale' from 2001:1458:202:56::100:1b
2023-05-08 11:05:44   info   : Server 'node-a' failed
2023-05-08 11:05:44   info   : Stopped Read-Service client session [2]
2023-05-08 11:07:03   info   : Found matching user 'maxscale'@'%' for client 'maxscale'@'2001:1458:202:56::111:1b' with sufficient privileges.
2023-05-08 11:07:03   info   : New session for server node-a. Connections : 1
2023-05-08 11:07:03   info   : Started Read-Service client session [3] for 'maxscale' from 2001:1458:202:56::111:1b
2023-05-08 11:07:03   info   : Server 'node-a' failed
2023-05-08 11:07:03   info   : Stopped Read-Service client session [3]
2023-05-08 11:10:39   info   : Found matching user 'maxscale'@'%' for client 'maxscale'@'2001:1458:202:56::111:1b' with sufficient privileges.
```

This is after setting `log_info=true` for maxscale and recreating maxscale MySQL user with `mysql_native_password`. Following is the user info.

```
mysql> select * from user where user='maxscale'\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                    Host: %
                    User: maxscale
             Select_priv: N
             Insert_priv: N
             Update_priv: N
             Delete_priv: N
             Create_priv: N
               Drop_priv: N
             Reload_priv: N
           Shutdown_priv: N
            Process_priv: N
               File_priv: N
              Grant_priv: N
         References_priv: N
              Index_priv: N
              Alter_priv: N
            Show_db_priv: Y
              Super_priv: N
   Create_tmp_table_priv: N
        Lock_tables_priv: N
            Execute_priv: N
         Repl_slave_priv: N
        Repl_client_priv: Y
        Create_view_priv: N
          Show_view_priv: N
     Create_routine_priv: N
      Alter_routine_priv: N
        Create_user_priv: N
              Event_priv: N
            Trigger_priv: N
  Create_tablespace_priv: N
                ssl_type: 
              ssl_cipher: 0x
             x509_issuer: 0x
            x509_subject: 0x
           max_questions: 0
             max_updates: 0
         max_connections: 0
    max_user_connections: 0
                  plugin: mysql_native_password
   authentication_string: *2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2629D1E19
        password_expired: N
   password_last_changed: 2023-05-08 09:02:05
       password_lifetime: NULL
          account_locked: N
        Create_role_priv: N
          Drop_role_priv: N
  Password_reuse_history: NULL
     Password_reuse_time: NULL
Password_require_current: NULL
         User_attributes: NULL
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
mysql> show grants for 'maxscale'@'%';
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for maxscale@%                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SHOW DATABASES, REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO `maxscale`@`%` |
| GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`columns_priv` TO `maxscale`@`%`          |
| GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`db` TO `maxscale`@`%`                    |
| GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`procs_priv` TO `maxscale`@`%`            |
| GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`proxies_priv` TO `maxscale`@`%`          |
| GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`tables_priv` TO `maxscale`@`%`           |
| GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`user` TO `maxscale`@`%`                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The MaxScale log might have more information. The log is located in `/var/log/maxscale/maxscale.log`. Another thing to check is the default authentication method used by those databases. MaxScale requires that the `mysql_native_password` is used as `caching_sha2_password` is not supported due it not being compatible with database proxies like MaxScale that use multiple nodes.

Comment: I have checked the maxscale log but it does not show anything related to a sucessful connection with the mysql server or any such information. I will update the maxscale log in the question for further reference. `mysql_native_password` might not be the issue as well because in the working server(node1) maxscale user uses `caching_sha2_password` and its working fine. Also it can login to all 3 servers, just cannot execute queries on other 2 server. I am anyway checking further on this avenue.

Comment: MaxScale will not work with any user that uses `caching_sha2_password`. The set of [authentication plugins](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-2208-authentication-modules/) that MaxScale supports does not include `caching_sha2_password` and thus you'll receive an error when MaxScale authenticates to the backend databases. One thing to debug this further is to enable info level logging by adding `log_info=true` under the `[maxscale]` section. This will log much more information for each connection which should help you figure out why it's not working.

Comment: @markusjm could you please see the edit 3 in the question. I have recreated the maxscale user with `mysql_native_password` and tried which leads to the same results. It looks like it can connect to mysql but the connection gets dropped after that.

Comment: Could you open a bug report on the MariaDB Jira under the [MaxScale project](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MXS)? I think it might be easier to investigate this there instead of on StackOverflow comments, especially if there's a need to attach files to the issue (e.g. a network trace).

Comment: @markusjm I was able to get in touch with MariaDB support team. According to them, the issue is because the MariaDB free version only support a single server and their pricing pages are being updated so this information is not available anywhere in the error log or the website. Sorry for the noise and thanks for the support.

Comment: Could you still open a bug report about this on the MariaDB Jira under the MaxScale project?

Comment: Sure. Please find the issue at https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MXS-4609

Answer (score 0):

After the long debugging session, we concluded that MaxScale cannot query the MySQL servers if the hostname does not resolve an ipv6 even after adding `address=0.0.0.0`. The issue discussion is here https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MXS-4609 and Maxscale logging is improved to provide more information here https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/MaxScale/commit/f8b0c405ad80a5e70c1e5f770ac0e2d02f81d30f

Credits to @markus on the complete debugging support.